# ItemsPanelTemplate in XAML ignores [ContentProperty] attribute

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a custom Panel where I declared a custom property to hold the content (I don't want to use Children for the content):

```
[ContentProperty(Name = "PanelContent")]
public class CustomPanel : Panel
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PanelContentProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("PanelContent", 
       typeof(Collection<UIElement>), typeof(CustomPanel), 
       new PropertyMetadata(new Collection<UIElement>(), null));

    public Collection<UIElement> PanelContent
    {
        get
        {
            return (Collection<UIElement>)GetValue(PanelContentProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly when used like this:

```
<CustomPanel>
   <TextBlock>A</TextBlock>
   <TextBlock>B</TextBlock>
</CustomPanel>
```

But when I want to use the panel as an ItemsPanelTemplate inside ItemsControl, the  ContentProperty attribute is ignored and adds everything to the **Children** collection, not the **PanelContent** collection:

```
<ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ReviewTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Reviews}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <CustomPanel></CustomPanel>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

This is not how it should work. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemspaneltemplate):

*An ItemsPanelTemplate object element should contain exactly one FrameworkElement-derived class that serves as the root element for items. In most cases this is a Panel-derived class. The expanded template serves as the parent for the realized items and there generally is more than one item. Therefore the XAML content property of the intended root element of an ItemsPanelTemplate should support a collection, as Panel.Children does.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Panel's GenerateChildren method, that is responsible for this task looks (as seen in [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx)) like

```
internal virtual void GenerateChildren()
{
    IItemContainerGenerator itemContainerGenerator = this._itemContainerGenerator;
    if (itemContainerGenerator != null)
    {
        using (itemContainerGenerator.StartAt(new GeneratorPosition(-1, 0), GeneratorDirection.Forward))
        {
            UIElement uIElement;
            while ((uIElement = (itemContainerGenerator.GenerateNext() as UIElement)) != null)
            {
                this._uiElementCollection.AddInternal(uIElement);
                itemContainerGenerator.PrepareItemContainer(uIElement);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, it always adds to this._uiElementCollection, which is the field backing the Children property.

Answer (score 1):

I think the ItemsPanelTemplate can only take Panel.Children as the target to layout items.  In fact, if you derive your CustomPanel from, say, ContentControl, you will find following exception message in metro style app:

```
Exception: The ItemsControl.ItemsPanelTemplate must have a derivative of Panel as the root element.
```

The documentation you linked might be a documentation bug which was copied from WPF time, when you still can insert visuals programmatically into visual tree.  In Metro app, there's no longer a way to put your own list of UIElements into visual tree without using Panel.Children.

Answer (score 0):

Because ItemsPanelTemplate is used by ItemsControl to create and use the Panel and it's not XAML that does anything. ItemsControl will simply call Panel.Children.Add no matter what ContentProperty is set to.

Panel is supposed to only layout the children and never style them. So all you must do os only override Arrange and Measure methods. All panels only do that.

For styling and any other logic you must use another approach.

Comment: That's not entirely true. Take a look at the `RichTextColums` Panel which is part of every Metro application you create in Visual Studio.

Comment: Panel only changes layout, RichTextColumns supports laying out its children, it does paging, column layouts. And all it does is Measure and Arrange its children. I will look into source code via reflector but I am pretty sure, Panels do not add/change styles. They may override style resources but source of Panel will not contain any code for style.

Comment: Indeed, and that's exactly what I want to achieve. I never said anything about styling. I just want to use a different property for the content (not `Children`). Sadly, the specified property name is not honored by `ItemsControl`.

Comment: Then why are you creating property and applying ContentProperty on it? Why dont you just override Measure and Arrange methods and set bounds (x,y,width,height) for panel's children. Panel already has property called "Children"

Comment: Because I want the Panel to create StackPanels as columns where the content will be inserted. In other words, the content elements won't be direct children of the panel. That's exactly what the RichTextColumns panel does, but for only one element instead of multiple.

Comment: No panel hosts another panel to do layout, you will have to override methods Measure and Arrange, that's the only way. Have you checked source of RichTextColumns panel?

Comment: That's just semantics. The `RichTextColumns` panel doesn't use Children for its content at design time (that's why it has the `ContentProperty` attribute). It creates its own child elements and adds them to the Children collection. It does not simply rearrange the child elements.